# basic help to call python from unix

Tags: python, unix

Hi I am pretty new to python so I have been playing around with it. I recently created 2 files for some process I am working on which seems to be working while running python but doing nothing when write python name.py argv at the unix command line. It is probably something basic and I would appreciate some help. 
1st file (make_dir.py)

```
import os
import sys

def main():
    directory = sys.argv[1]
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
      os.makedirs(directory)
```

at unix terminal I write

```
python make_dir.py /home/user/Python/Test/
```

result: Test folder is not created.

the second file has probably the same issue.
2nd file directory.py

```
import sys
import os

def main():
  os.chdir(sys.argv[1])
  File = open(sys.argv[2] , 'w')
  File.write(sys.argv[3])
  File.close()
```

at unix terminal:

```
python directory.py /home/user/Python/TEST/ a.log "this is a test"
```

a.log is not created.
If I got some error messages I probably could figure it out but no messages. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're defining a function called `main`, but never call it. Do:

```
import os
import sys

def main():
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) for more details about this idiom.

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually calling `main`. Simply adding `main()` at the end of script would suffice, but usually this idiom is used:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This would call `main` if the script was executed directly, and not just imported from another module.

See [executing modules as scripts](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts)

Answer (score 1):

Python is not C and `def main` is not magic. There is no predefined execution entry point for Python programs. All your code is doing is defining a main function (not running it), so Python defines `main` and then stops (as you requested).

You must call `main()` explicitly if you want it to execute. You should use this idiom:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`__name__` is a magic variable created at the module level that contains the module's name. If `__name__` is `'__main__'`, it means the current module was not imported but was run directly. This idiom allows you to use a Python file as both a module (something you can import--where `main()` should not automatically run) and as a script (where `main()` should run automatically).